# z-stacked series of histograms plots

Tags: r

I have a time series of histogram plots of a population that I would like to represent in one figure.  I am trying to avoid putting all of the histograms in one x,y plot which gets very messy.   Rather, I would like to make a figure that plots a series of histograms with only an x-axis (for my data, the shape and x-value is all that matters) with each histogram vertically stacked on top of the other. In other words, I could make a bunch of individual histogram plots, export them to Illustrator, and place them one on top of the other in a vertical row and label the vertical "z-axis" as time, but it seems like one should be able to do this in R

Comment: You should try to explain this to someone you trust to give you a candid opinion regarding its clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Within the function `hist`, one can set `freq=FALSE` to in order to plot density rather than frequency. This will scale the y-axis of your histograms in a way that focuses the attention on the shape rather than the amplitude. But, even by using the default frequency histogram, you would have the same shape to your plots.

Here is an example plot where your device is divided into 4 rows and 1 column. Each histogram is of a different distribution, but all plots use the same binning for the histogram (i.e. `breaks` argument):

#### Example 1:

```
set.seed(1)
f1 <- rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1)
f2 <- rnorm(100, mean=3, sd=3)
f3 <- rnorm(100, mean=4, sd=1)
f4 <- rnorm(100, mean=7, sd=3)

breaks <- pretty(c(f1, f2, f3, f4), n=20)
x11(width=4, height=8)
op <- par(mfcol=c(4,1))
hist(f1, freq=FALSE, breaks=breaks)
hist(f2, freq=FALSE, breaks=breaks)
hist(f3, freq=FALSE, breaks=breaks)
hist(f4, freq=FALSE, breaks=breaks)
par(op)
```

Possibly more along the lines of what you are interested in, is the following - Each sequential histogram could be a time `t`. By reducing the margins a bit, you are able to track the progression of the shape through time:

#### Example 2:

```
set.seed(1)

N <- 100
M <- 7
MEAN <- c(1:M)
SD <- MEAN*0.2+1
RES <- list()

for(i in seq(M)){
    RES[[i]] <- rnorm(N, mean=MEAN[[i]], sd=SD[[i]])
}


breaks <- pretty(unlist(RES), n=20)
x11(width=4, height=10)
op <- par(mfcol=c(M,1), mar=c(1,3,0,0), oma=c(3,2,1,1))
for(i in seq(M)){
    h1 <- hist(RES[[i]], breaks=breaks, plot=FALSE)
    plot(h1$mids, h1$densit, t="n", xlab="", ylab="", xaxt="n")
    grid()
    lines(h1$mids, h1$densit, t="S")
    text(par()$usr[1], par()$usr[3]+(par()$usr[4]-par()$usr[3])*0.9, labels=paste("t", i), pos=4)
    if(i == M){
        axis(1)
    } else {
        axis(1, labels=FALSE)
    }
}
mtext("Density", outer=TRUE, side=2, line=0)
par(op)
```

[image]